# Data analysis projects fora newly renovated desktop?

Tags: discussion

I just renovated a desktop that had been in storage for a while, and I'd like to come up with some big data analysis projects to run on it in the background. Does anyone have any ideas, know of any data sets, or algorithms or processes that could be cool to check out?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem to related directly to astronomy.

Comment: ditto @Hohmannfan's reason for downvote, this should probably be in a computing related stack exchange

Comment: I'm voting to re-open this question, since the answers here can be "what astronomical computing requires help". For example, we can suggest SETI and other similar programs and/or some other questions that require CPU support, both from the OP and from others.

Comment: @starrtennis Contact me (see my profile) if you're willing to compile and run CSPICE programs on your machine. I'm constantly running these and could use some CPU support.